# How to learn OpenGL by example, say, building a rotating globe?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I have two years of experience on iPhone programming but totally new to OpenGL. What should I pick up in order to build a rotating globe on iPhone? What I want to archive:

- a 3G globe shown on an iPhone
- basically a 3D ball with a texture map on it
- when a user drag on the screen, the globe rotates

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you are completely new to OpenGl like me than I would suggest you to follow this link to get you started

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html

enjoy

Edit:

Try this too

[how to replace images in puzzle game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754664/how-to-replace-images-in-puzzle-game/4755290#4755290)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson)'s Course on OpenGL (ES). It's [available on iTunes](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032) (for free):

> The videos of the Advanced iPhone
>   Development class I taught this past
>   semester at the Madison Area Technical
>   College are now available for free on
>   iTunes U. These videos amount to over
>   35 hours of HD content, covering more
>   advanced iPhone development topics
>   such as Core Animation,
>   multithreading, Quartz 2-D drawing,
>   and OpenGL ES. The course notes that
>   accompany the class are available for
>   download here in VoodooPad format, or
>   for viewing here in HTML. Links to all
>   sample applications used for the class
>   are present in the notes.

[Source](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/06/03/advanced-iphone-development-course-now-itunes-u)

Answer (score 1):

Many people would suggest that you try the NeHe Tutorials for OpenGL, and while I do think that they cover a few features of the OpenGL API, I would instead recommend buying a book on OpenGL if you are serious about learning it. Of course, learning how to write programs using OpenGL comes with practice, but reading the books helps you understand how and why the API is designed how it is, and also introduces you to the graphics pipeline, which is crucial in understanding how your function calls are really processed. I would personally recommend the OpenGL Superbible, but I have heard the the Red Book is good as well. Here's a [link](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/) to a free HTML file containing an older version of the Red Book.