# cocos2d game sample based on gameloop?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I want to develop 2d game through Cocos2d.but i could not find 
any tutorial based on the following.I want one game loop and one draw screen.can I do Multiple sprite animations within one scene..(translating World etc).where can i find tutorial how to use those classes which are coccos2d?

`-(void)gameloop
{
  calculation();
  drawImage();
  drawImage1();
}`

Answer (score 0):

[How to learn OpenGL by example, say, building a rotating globe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743521/how-to-learn-opengl-by-example-say-building-a-rotating-globe/4743595#4743595)

Comment: yes you can check the other link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754664/how-to-replace-images-in-puzzle-game/4755290#4755290

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, you do not have to know opengl essentials to use cocos2d. cocos2d is quite simple yet awesome!. Just download the cocos2d 0.99.5 and it comes with sample tests. You will be able to find almost all of the things you want to do in a game i.e. animations, touches, moving sprites, particle system etc etc 
 so just go to:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/