# 3D globe of earth model for iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any one know of an OpenGL ES example of an interactive globe/earth for the iPhone.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322111/any-one-know-of-an-opengl-es-example-of-an-interactive-globe-earth-for-the-iphone)

I am looking for a 3D globe of earth which is written preferably in Objective-C and works on the iPad.

I can't seem to find any online.

Comment: what do mean "3D globe of earth which is written preferably in Objective-C" do you need the code, that renders it? or a textured model?

Comment: So... You're looking for a feature complete (presumably open-source) Cocoa class that can display a 3D globe (presumably in a view). Odd though this may seem, I suspect you'll probably have to construct one yourself. I'd be tempted to start reading about [OpenGL ES](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and take it from there. :-)

Comment: See also [How to learn OpenGL by example, say, building a rotating globe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743521/how-to-learn-opengl-by-example-say-building-a-rotating-globe)

Comment: As farfetched as the request is, no need to downvote.

Comment: I don't think there is anything far fetched about this request.  It's quite plausible that someone might have written a 3D globe for the iPad and is selling a license to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can try [this](http://code.google.com/p/iphonewavefrontloader/) - this is the loader for the wave front obj loader. You can find the textured model of globe (i think there are lots of them in the Internet) and then export it using Maya, 3DsMax, Blender etc.